# Edit function is not properly working in angular JS

Tags: angularjs

When I add any data I am getting values in text box instead of getting it in span.And also after the data gets added I am getting done button instead of getting Update button.Find my full code here:https://jsfiddle.net/GowthamG/jL5oza04/
Is there any error?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var app=angular.module("mainapp",[]);
app.controller('mycontrol',function($scope){
    $scope.filters=[];
    $scope.add=function(filter){
        $scope.filters.push(filter);
            $scope.filter={};
        };
        $scope.update = function (index) {
            $scope.editing = $scope.filters.indexOf(index);
        };



<table border="2">
    <tr>
        <td>FirstName</td>
        <td>LastName</td>
        <td>Fees</td>
        <td>E-Course</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="filter in filters track by $index">
        <td><span ng-hide="update">{{filter.fname}}</span>
            <input type="text" ng-show="update" ng-model="filter.fname">
        </td>
        <td><span ng-hide="update">{{filter.lname}}</span>
            <input type="text" ng-show="update" ng-model="filter.lname">
        </td>
        <td><span ng-hide="update">{{filter.ffees}}</span>
            <input type="number" ng-show="update" ng-model="filter.ffees">
        </td>
        <td><span ng-hide="update">{{filter.eroll}}</span>
            <input type="text" ng-show="update" ng-model="filter.eroll">
        </td>
        <td>
            <button ng-hide="update" ng-click="update = true; update($index)">Update</button>
            <button ng-show="update" ng-click="update = false">Done</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button ng-click="remove($index)">Remove</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Where is your add method called from HTML? Also, i don't see your update variable getting updated anywhere in the code on add. Please post the full code. There also seems to be errors in your HTML and controller code is also incomplete.

Comment: If I am uploading the full code,it shows that you post has max codes and I can't post the question

Comment: Please create a fiddle or a plunkr then.

Comment: I have updated your plunkr https://jsfiddle.net/jL5oza04/1/  Please check if your angularjs library is getting loaded properly

Comment: Thank you...But after adding data why it is displayed in text box instead of span and also after adding why done button appears instead of update...Can you clear it?

Comment: Remove angular tag...

Comment: @GOWTHAMG Check the answer below and if it helped, please mark answer as accepted :)

Comment: @GOWTHAMG  You just have to set update to false after you add any record. $scope.update = false;  I have updated the fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/jL5oza04/2/

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the value of `$scope.update` in your add functionality to hide the inputs. Now the values will be shown in a span with update button.

```
$scope.add=function(filter){
    $scope.filters.push(filter);
        $scope.update=false;
    };
```

**Working Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/kz8uLg10/2/